# Increasing Screen Resolution to more than limit and scaling to origional

Tags: windows, linux, laptop, resolution, intel-graphics

I have a laptop, with Screen Resolution - 1366x768 (most common) - I want to increase it further to 1600x900 (or higher), in the same ratio. I want to scale the higher resolution on my current screen to fit it.

I found `xrandr` with command `xrandr --output LVDS1 --scale 1.4x1.4`, this worked but again resulted to another problem, it does the scaling thing but the cursor is still blocked into the native screen resolution and I am not able to move it further, I found that the bug is already filed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/883319).

Also this command was only for Linux, I wanted to do this thing with both Linux and Windows (including Windows 8). I want a similar software that is bug free (at least not a major bug like this) and that supports Windows as well (or two separate software for Windows and Linux).

Any help is appreciated and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I posted an [answer on AskUbuntu on how to set resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174453/i-am-not-able-to-set-resolution-at-1280-x-1024/174466#174466) using `xrandr`.

I have tried it and it works fine. But this is only for linux.

Comment: Ok, I will look to it ASAP!